# The example of strict evaluation from Simon Marlow's book "Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell"

Tags: haskell, concurrency, lazy-evaluation, weak-head-normal-form

Simon Marlow in his book "Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell" writes:

> The insert operation hadthis line:
>
> ```
> putMVar m (Map.insert name number book)
> ```
>
> This places in the MVar the unevaluated expression `Map.insert name number book`.
> If we were to do many insert operations consecutively, the MVar would build up a large chain of unevaluated expressions.
> To get brief locking and no space leaks, we need to use
> a trick:
>
> ```
> let book' = Map.insert name number book
> putMVar m book'
> seq book' (return ())
> ```
>
> With this sequence, we’re storing an unevaluated expression in the MVar, but it is evaluated immediately after the putMVar.

I don't get it. `seq a b` operation evaluates `a` in weak head normal form. So there will be unevaluated expression. As I can see only the Map constructor will be evaluated and all of it contents will be unevaluated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As I can see only the `Map` constructor will be evaluated and all of it contents will be unevaluated.

Internally, the `Map` type is implemented using a strict tree. Either the whole tree spine gets evaluated, or none of it.  Here's a snippet from the library code:

```
data Map k a  = Bin {-# UNPACK #-} !Size !k a !(Map k a) !(Map k a)
              | Tip
```

The strictness annotations (`!`) prevent unevaluated values to be stored as subtrees. So, if we evaluate a `Map k a` value to weak head normal form, we actually fully evaluate the tree spine.

Comment: Thanks! I defenently had to look at the Map source code before asking a question ;)

Answer (score 1):

`Map` in `Map.insert` is not map constructor. It is a module name. The function [`insert :: Ord k => k -> a -> Map k a -> Map k a`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Map.insert) is called here. Its result *will* get evaluated to WHNF before `return ()` is calculated as the next computational step in the combined IO action, thanks to the call to `seq`. You can consult [the source of `insert`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/src/Data.Map.Internal.html#insert) for details. It does a lot of forcing through bang patterns and such.